# How can I implement a function for invoking any (arbitrary) function with its (arbitrary) arguments?

Tags: c++, reflection, functional-programming, polymorphism

I would like to have the following:

```
void foo( 
    /* something representing a function f */,
    /* arguments a1, a2, etc. in some form */ ) 
{
    /* magic - invoke f(a1, a2, etc.)*/
}

/* ... */

void bar(float f, char* s);
void baz(int i);
/* etc. */

int main() {
    /* ... */
    foo(bar, SomeKindOfTransformationOrNoneAtAll(f, s));
    foo(baz, SomeKindOfTransformationOrNoneAtAll(i));
    /* etc. */
}
```

Can I implement `foo()`? That is, can I write a function which takes an arbitrary other function, and a bunch of arguments (varargs, or vector, or list, or what have you) and invokes the passed function with the passed arguments?

If this is possible, is there a library which facilitates it? Or some common idiom for it?

**Note:**

- I do not want to bind the arguments to the function outside foo(), but rather inside it. So, `foo()` must take more than just a single function*/std::function/etc. parameter.

Comment: Why not bind outside? It's far superior to passing them inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variadic templates can indeed do this.

```
template<typename T, typename... Args> void foo(T func, Args&&... args) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Then simply pass the arguments directly to `foo`. This is called perfect forwarding. However with lambdas it's really more idiomatic to bind them there.

```
template<typename T> void foo(T func) {
    func();
}    
int main() {
    foo([] { baz(param1, param2); });
}
```

You can capture the params if they're not constants. This is a superior choice because you can convert the template easily into a non-template if you want, and the issue of parameter lifetime or not is dodged because the lambda user can capture however they need. You can take multiple objects this way instead of just one, as a variadic pack can only occur once. And finally, you don't have to shit around with making it pick a single function pointer thingie when using named functions.

Comment: Damn the distractions. You were just a bit faster... You gonna add `std::function` too?

Comment: Thanks, but I need to be able to use foo-like functions generically, and I'm doubtful that will be possible with templates.

Comment: @einpoklum: Why not? It certainly can be done. allocator::construct does this in the stdlib.

Comment: I'm not familiar with allocator::construct, I'll look into it, but I may want to do something like `for (const auto& f_and_a : my_collection) { foo(f_and_a.first, f_and_a.second); }`.

Comment: @einpoklum: That's perfectly legit with the variadic foo that I showed above.

Comment: Hmm. In hindsight I may not have asked exactly the right question. No fault of yours of course. I'll rethink things and maybe ask again.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for is [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

So, something like :

```
void foo(std::function<void()> fun) {
    fun();
}

foo(std::bind(bar, 0.1f, "abc"));
foo(std::bind(baz, 42));
```

Comment: whoever downvoted this, can you please explain why ?

Comment: Please see my edit. Can I move the 'bind's into the function?

Comment: @einpoklum : then variadic templates are probably the way to go. It's difficult to see from your example code why that's needed though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to decide at the site of the caller what the function should be called with.

The simplest solution is to use a lambda with std::function:

```
void foo(std::function<void(void)> f) { // std::function has strong magic
    // whatever you want here
    f();
    // whatever you want here
}

/* ... */

void bar(float f, char* s);
void baz(int i);
/* etc. */

int main() {
    foo( [f, s]() { bar(f, s); } );
    foo( [&i]() { baz(i) } );
    /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: @einpoklum, - in that case, use the variadic template solution posted by Puppy.